# Multiple IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column (A1:A) with URLs of the Sheets I want to IMPORTRANGE. The problem is it's open end and I can't just do
={IMPORTRANGE(A1,"Sheet1!A1:A");IMPORTRANGE(A2,"Sheet1!A1:A")}
as the list of URLs is open end (indefinite). Since I cannot use ARRAYFORMULA with IMPORTRANGE, I was wondering if there is an alternative to it. I'd also like to have a URL next to IMPORTRANGE data, so I know what URL the data shown came from. Maybe someone has a clue.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YhLJpy_p39pDvTKfjyOKQMN0W_TDz95E9XsmtOJV-GQ

Comment: But this one is working right? 
`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A2; B2);IMPORTRANGE(A3; B3);IMPORTRANGE(A4; B4)}; "select * where Col1 is not null")`

Comment: yes, it's working, but it's not open end. It works only as long as I hard code the URLs, but when I don't know how many URLs will be there.

Comment: I see what you want to achieve. I am not sure if you can do that. However, keep in mind that the more importranges you have the more laggy the file will be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use script for that. `IMPORTRAGE` not working inside `ARRAYFORMULA` is usually solved with importing using scripts.

In case of formulas with import failure tolerance and source markings here are a few solutions.

#### Solution 1 - many `QUERY`, same number of `IMPORTRANGE`

Try this:

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    {
      IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(A2; B2); "SELECT '" & A2 & "', Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"); {""\ ""});
      IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(A3; B3); "SELECT '" & A3 & "', Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"); {""\ ""});
      IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(A4; B4); "SELECT '" & A4 & "', Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL"); {""\ ""})
    }
  );
  "WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL
   LABEL Col1 'Source',
         Col2 'Imported Data'"
)
```

[image]

#### Solution 2 - one `QUERY`, twice the `IMPORTRANGE`

You can use `IFERROR` in case import will go wrong.

Here is a possible solution for you (`IFERROR` and source URLs) (one formula in `E1`):

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    {
      IFERROR({IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(IMPORTRANGE(A2; B2))); A2)\ IMPORTRANGE(A2; B2)}; {""\ ""});
      IFERROR({IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(IMPORTRANGE(A3; B3))); A3)\ IMPORTRANGE(A3; B3)}; {""\ ""});
      IFERROR({IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(IMPORTRANGE(A4; B4))); A4)\ IMPORTRANGE(A4; B4)}; {""\ ""})
    }
  );
  "WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL
   LABEL Col1 'Source',
         Col2 'Imported Data'"
)
```

[image]